# Find conjugate harmonic function of $u=x^2+y^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative, cauchy-riemann-equations

Find conjugate harmonic function of $u=x^2+y^2$?

By Cauchy-Riemann equations,

$u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$.

Now, $v_x=-u_y=-2y$ and $v_y=u_x=2x$.

We have $dv=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} dx+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} dy$.

$\implies dv=-2ydx+2xdy$. How can I find $v$?

Comment: $u$ is not harmonic ($\Delta u = u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 4 \ne 0$), so there cannot be a harmonic conjugate. Or did you mean $u(x, y) = x^2 -y^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $u$ is not harmonic, I'm pretty sure you wanted to write $y=x^2-y^2$. In that case by the Cauchy-Riemann equations:$$v_y=2x\implies v=2xy+\phi(x), $$  also we have that $$2y=2y+\phi'(x) \implies \phi(x)=C.$$ So the harmonic conjugate is $v(x,y) =2xy+C.$$